# Using SOLR how do I return the best result for a set of integer preferences

Tags: solr

I'm trying to create a query that returns the best product depending on a few required attributes and a few optional ones that just affect the weighting.

Properties 1-3 required

Properties 4-5 optional

ratings 1-3 optional

The data is structured in the solr db like so:

```
property1 (string)
property2 (string)
property3 (string)
property4 (string)
property5 (string)

rating1 (int)
rating2 (int)
rating3 (int)
```

The query I've created so far get's me close, but it does not take in account how close the optional fields are to the specific requested value.

An example is the ratings are valued 1-5 for arbitrary properties such as efficiency or usefulness. I need it to acknowledge that if the user wants rating1 set to 4 then values 3 and 5 are still valid, just equally less so.  Also a value of 2 is weighted more then 1. So it basically creates a scale based on how far the product is from the desired rating value.

```
defType = dismax
sort = score desc
fl = entity_id,score,property4,property5,rating1,rating2,rating3
fq = property1:215 property2:45 property3:17
bq = property4:(H)^5 OR property5:(87)^5 OR rating1:(1)^5 OR rating2:(3)^5 OR rating3:(5)^5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the rules for doing the math on the rating, I would go with a [function query](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Function+Queries). You could do any math that you think works best in this case and the result could affect the boost score.